# Corona native.newVideo causes App crash when playing downloaded video from Document Directory

Tags: lua, coronasdk, crash

We are downloading a video from server in document Directory & playing it using "native.newVideo" code shown in API (as it is).

But app is getting crashed, error: "Unfortunately app is stopped"

We've tried many many solutions entire day but couldn't fix it.
We've ensured video file is there. When same downloaded video is played using media.play it is getting played.

When we keep the video directly into Resource directory it is getting played with native.newVideo code.

No error in ADB logcat. (Android only App)

- The downloaded video is successfully played using media.play
- Even we have tried changing Directory (temp-directory) , but it Fail's

"We Need to download it in Document Directory & Play it using native.newVideo()"

the following is the code we are using:

```
local function playVideo()

    local video = native.newVideo( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 320, 480 )
    video:load( "Latin.mp4",system.DocumentsDirectory )
    video:play()
end

local function networkListener( event )

    if ( event.isError ) then

        print( "Network error - download failed" )

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

        print( "Progress Phase: ready" )

        playVideo()

    end
end

local params = {}
params.progress = true

network.download("http://sirma.no/Latin.mp4", "GET", networkListener, params, "Latin.mp4", system.DocumentsDirectory )
```

Comment: I don't have any Android devices available for the moment so I can’t try the actual video player but I could download the file without any problem. I will throw out a guess here and say that it might be due to the format. I checked the video in VLC and it uses codec “MPEG-4 Video (mp4v)” but it doesn’t state if it’s H.263 or any other codec. What I would do is make sure that I have a MP4 file that uses H.263 codec and test it out on my device. This is only a guess as I don’t see anything wrong with your code. Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html